# python - selenium - Can't import previously exported cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I'm trying to make sure that the login to the site I make with Selenium doesn't have to repeat it every time but that it remains logged in when selenium reopens the next time.
So what I do is login to the site, then wait a few seconds and request the cookies with `get_cookies` and save them in a file. then I close everything. now I start a new, fresh Selenium, go to the same site and import cookies, one by one using `add_cookies` inside a for cycle. I get this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.UnableToSetCookieException: Message: unable to set cookie

This is the essential code I use for get the cookies:

```
driver.get('https://login.site.com')
# here the code to login
# now I'm successfully logged in, so wait 5 seconds and get cookies...
time.sleep(5)
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookie.pkl", "wb"))
driver.close()
```

this is the essential code I use to add the cookies:

```
driver.get('https://login.site.com')
cookie = pickle.load(open("cookie.pkl", "rb")) #loading from pickle file
for i in cookie:
    driver.add_cookie(i) # GET ERROR!!!
```

Comment: none of the questions already presented was helpful to me

Comment: Some websites, particularly those with strict security policies, may not allow cookies to be set from outside sources.